how to add a custom confirmation prompt using outlook addin
How to add a confirmation prompt before sending an email just wanted to ask once more to confirm as a prompt to the user, I am using Outlook add-in ( dotnet with vanilla JS).
I have gone through the documentation but it refers to using "Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync" but this is not what I was expecting.
The expectation is to use this kind of confirmation prompt. how can i create my confirmation prompt like this?


Instead of using DialogAPI onSend event, there is the simple way to achieve exactly what you need and display the prompt which is called "Smart Alerts". There is a difference between Smart Alerts and the on-send feature. There are a lot of resources on "Smart Alert" feature of Outlook add-on. The following article is the great way to start: Handle OnMessageSend and OnAppointmentSend events in your Outlook add-in with Smart Alerts. The example of the implementation, similar functionality you are asking about, but for attachment check can be found Automatically check for an attachment before a message is sent.
